# Accessing xibs embedded in static pod

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods 1.8.4.

I want to make an update of an existing pod (i'm not the original author) to update its dependancy to firebase from 4.10 to 6.10.
To be able to build, I've had to make my pod a statis library `s.static_framework = true` when using the last firebase version.

Now, when I try to instanciate a viewController which xib is a part of my pod, the example crashes:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Imotep/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B165BF4E-D41E-40BE-84C3-5DC5317DB3DE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BFE3CA2C-5244-42B3-9237-EB6CBBE133F5/MyPod_Example.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyPodViewController'
```

I've tried to put the xibs into a .bundle by adding this to my podspec:
`s.resource_bundle = { 'MyPod' => [ 'MyPod/Classes/UI/*.{xib}' ] }`

Know in the main bundle of my example app I correctly have a MyPod.bundle containing my nibs. But I can't seem to acces those bundled nibs ><

`Bundle(for: MyPodViewController.self)` returns the main bundle and `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyPodViewController", ofType: "nib")` doesn't find anything.

How should I do to make the app fetch xibs in the bundle? 
Do I even need them to be in a bundle? 
I'm completely lost :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need them to be in a bundle.

Input:

[image]

In your `Podfile`:

```
s.static_framework = true
s.resource_bundles = {
  'bundleResources' => ['staticPod/Assets/*.png', 'staticPod/Assets/*.xib']
}
```

Just check if you don't have also a `s.resources` entry, because it messes the bundle path.

In your swift class:

```swift
guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bundleResources", withExtension: "bundle") else {
    return
}

guard let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL) else {
    return
}

let vc: UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "TestViewController", bundle: bundle)

self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Output:

[image]

It works called from both inside or outside the Pod.

Comment: Nice! It indeed works. I didn't even try getting the `Bundle` url and init a `Bundle` with it it because `Bundle.allBundles` didn't list my bundle, so I guessed getting its url would not work.

Comment: The documentation is a little vague, but seems like the pod resources bundle only appears in `Bundle.allBundles` after you explicitly loads it from the URL